# 404 error with using ajax jquery in nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I want to do add some tags when the condition is true by using Ajax jquery and nodejs:

My route:

```
const manageKeyword_route = require("./routes/keywordRoute");

app.use("/manageKeyword", manageKeyword_route);

router.get("/createNonExist/:tagName", KeywordCtrl.apiCreateNotExistedKeyword);
```

And my ajax script is:

```
<script>
         if((true){
               $.ajax({
                    data: {"tagName": "example-tag"},
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/manageKeyword/createNonExist',
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: (function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    }),
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
               });
           }
  </script>
```

I think everything is correct But I am tired of facing 404 not found error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `data: {"tagName": "example-tag" },` and used `url: '/manageKeyword/createNonExist/' + "example-tag",` and it worked.

Edit:

It is better to be solved by a post type:
In nodejs:

```
router.post("/createNonExist", KeywordCtrl.apiCreateNotExistedKeyword);
```

and the Ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
      // type: "GET",
      // url: `/manageKeyword/createNonExist/${tag}`,
      data: {"tagName" : "example-tag"},
      type: "POST",
      url: `/manageKeyword/createNonExist`,
      cache: false,
      timeout: 5000,
      success: (function (res) {
                           
      }),
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
          }
      });
```